# Seleccionar toda la casilla de un DataGridView

Tags: c#

Quería saber como hacer para al clickear en una celda se seleccione todo el contenido, porque solo se queda para editar.
PD: SelectAll() serviría pero como es devexpress.

Answer (score 1):

Si solo quieres permitir seleccionar, sin que entre en edicion, deberias definir el grid como `ReadOnly = true`

Por otro lado para seleccionar la row completa define

[DataGridView.SelectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

con la opcion `FullRowSelect` de esta forma se seleccionara la row completa.

Si quieres controlar cuando entra en edicion la celda podrias defini la propiedad [EditMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode(v=vs.110).aspx) con el valor `EditProgrammatically` y luego en el evento double click poner en edicion la celda

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
}
```

tambien recuerda definir el `SelectionMode = FullRowSelect`

Comment: si quiero que sea editable, y que se marque(sombree) todo el contenido al dar click a la celda.

Comment: edite la respuesta, valida lo nuevo que comento a ver si resuelve el problema

Answer (score 0):

A tu data dataGridView modifica la propiedad SelectionMode

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```